# Overriding only some virtual funtion of base class with the same name

Tags: c++

I have a base class with a virtual fonction `foo(int i)` and `foo()` (same name, not same arguments).
The derived class override only `foo()`.
Now the derived class doesn't knows `foo(int i)` anymore.

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo(int i) {
    std::cout << "Base::foo(int i)" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual void foo() {
    std::cout << "Base::foo()" << std::endl;
  };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  void foo() override {
    std::cout << "Derived::foo()" << std::endl;
  }
};


int main(const int ac, const char* const av[])
{
  Base base;
  base.foo();
  base.foo(42);

  Derived derived;
  derived.foo();
  derived.foo(42);//ERROR : Function unknown
}
```

Should output :

```bash
Base::foo()
Base::foo(int i)
Derived::foo()
Base::foo(int i)
```

**Where does the problem come from and what would be the solutions?**
The derived class will sometimes override `foo()`, sometimes `foo(int i)` and sometimes both.

#### Note

If I go through the base class it works, but this solution is not ideal in my program :

```
Derived derived;
Base* pBase = &derived;
pBase->foo();
pBase->foo(42); //WORK
```

### Edit

Okay, I found on [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hiding-of-all-overloaded-methods-with-same-name-in-base-class-in-cpp/) that you need to use `using Base::foo;` in derivate class to import other foo functions.
**Someone know why and what's going one in the backgourd?** I don't like to not understand somethings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a **using declaration** inside derived class as shown below. In particular, a *using declaration* for a base-class member function (like `foo`) adds all the overloaded instances of that function to the scope of the derived class. Now you can override the version that takes an argument of type `int` and use the implementation of others that were added in the derived class' scope using the *using declaration*.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   //added this using declaration
   using Base::foo;
  void foo() override {
    std::cout << "Derived::foo()" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rdgQ2N7Cl)
The output of the above modified program is as you wanted:

```
Base::foo()
Base::foo(int i)
Derived::foo()
Base::foo(int i)
```

Comment: Tks ! It's working. But you know why it's working that way ? What do the using declaration ?

Comment: @MaximeCharrière have a look at: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule

Comment: @MaximeCharrière I have added some explanation in my answer about its working. Check out the updated answer.